# Footnote spacing in LaTeX

Tags: latex, margin, lyx, footnotes

I'm writing my dissertation and the grad school says I need a space between multiple footnotes and also the space between the text and the start of the footnotes is too small. Is there a way to do this?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

`\footnotesep` is the space between footnotes:

```
\setlength{\footnotesep}{0.5cm}
```

`\footins` is the space between the text body and the footnotes:

```
\setlength{\skip\footins}{2cm}
```

You might want to play around with the actual numbers, I've just chosen some values where you will actually see the difference.

Answer (score 8):

There's also a LaTeX package, [footmisc](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/footmisc), that's useful for manipulating footnote formatting.