# Latex: kerning between footnote marks and punctuation marks

Tags: latex, footnotes

#### Not the same as "[footnote spacing in latex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/783716/footnote-spacing-in-latex)".

When I add footnotes in latex, there is often a little bit of space due to the punctuation mark before them:

[image]

I can't help but feel this might be a little bit nicer if the footnote mark was a tiny tiny bit to the left, sort of like kerning. Any ideas how to do this? Especially if it automatically decides if it should do the kerning (as opposed to have one footnote with ! and one without).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add a small negative space using \! between the punctuation mark and the footnote.

As Jouni commented, \! is a math mode command causing latex to switch into math mode. This can be prevented by using the amstex package.

Comment: This works, but makes everything after it italic. Probably because footnote is so weird. But the idea of removing a tiny bit of space workds: it turns out I can just use \hspace{-0.8mm}.

Comment: Sorry, you're right. I had tried it on a footnote in math mode where everything worked fine. Looks like \! works only in math mode!

Comment: No, the reason \! makes things italic is that it is a math-mode command, and TeX thinks you forgot a $ and ever so helpfully inserts one for you. The very commonly used amsmath package redefines \! to work also in text mode.

Comment: @jug: If you mention the amsmath thing from Jouni, I'll mark this correct. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is now the [`fnpct`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fnpct) package that should do what you want automatically. It actually came from a related question on the TeX sister site: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56094/is-there-a-way-to-automatically-change-kerning-between-commas-full-stops-and-foo