# How do I force footnotes to the very bottom of the page when the page is not full?

Tags: layout, latex, footer, spacing, footnotes

In my thesis, I'm finding footnotes get placed just below the lowest text on the page. This means that the footnotes won't necessarily be placed at the end of the text box (of height `\textheight`) but on a half-full page will be quite a long way from the "foot" of the page.

Is it possible to make the footnotes go all the way to the bottom, for example by setting the footnote spacing as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/783716/footnote-spacing-in-latex) to a rubber length? I've tried

```
\setlength{\skip\footins}{1cm plus 25cm}
```

which puts all footnotes 1cm from the text as there's no *need* to expand the rubber length for layout purposes, and

```
\setlength{\skip\footins}{25cm plus 0cm minus 25cm}
```

tends to cause footnotes marks in the text to be the last line of the page, being especially unwilling to shrink this rubber length.

Perhaps there's something I'm missing about rubber lengths (like a way to make them more or less 'rubbery'?) or a way of using `\vfill` to position the footnotes?

Comment: Try posting on http://tex.stackexchange.com/

Comment: woops... i actually thought i was posting it on there (too many tabs, not enough sleep :/) i don't suppose it's possible to have questions moved between sites?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

It's possible to do with the [footmisc](http://ctan.org/pkg/footmisc) package.

You can do so with `\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}`